How do I change the field separator in CSV?
:NewDelimiter seems to add a separator to a list. I want to replace the default comma, with the intended tab. I am happy to specify it as \t.
I'm a little puzzled why Vim didn't recognize my intentions initially.
Unfortunately the data concerned is personal, so I can't give an extract.

Please [edit] and show the exact commands you entered, along with a description of the expected and actual behavior. You might also explain how the plugin's documentation failed to help you. I don't think we need to see any data but a sample would be easily made up. Here we go: chocolate, vanilla, strawberry

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest ;-)

It seems that following up the :NewDelimiter with an undo does the trick!
I'd love an explanation.

NewDelimiter actually replace the currently identified delimiter with a new one. e.g. change a comma separated file (,) into a semi-column separated file (;). I believe you want to help csv to use the correct delimiter.

You could:

Set the delimiter: :let g:csv_delim="\t"
Reinitialize the plugin: :CSVInit

Or alternatively:

Set the buffer delimiter: :let g:delimiter="\t"
Reinitialize the plugin (without changing the buffer delimiters): :CSVInit!

Remark: You can ask csv to automatically detect the delimiter considering a list starting with tab:
let g:csv_delim_test = "\t,;"

